How do we prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {1+e^{x}}{2}\right) ^{1/x} = \sqrt{e}$?
Wolfram Alpha gives me this solution:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {1+e^{x}}{2}\right) ^{1/x} = \sqrt{e}$$
But I have no idea how to get to that result.
I tried using L'Hopital but I found it impossible to get rid of the 1/x.
I also tried to use the fact that the result is $e^{1/2}$ and put an $e^{ln()}$ to use the logarithms properties, but I still couldn't simplify/rewrite the 1/x
I thought of using the squeeze theorem but I couldn't find functions that could work with the inequalities.

Related question but without much content: Limit of means function $M_p(s,t)=\left(\frac{s^p+t^p}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Application of: Why is the $0$th power mean defined to be the geometric mean?

According to the continuity of the $\exp$ function as well as the l'Hôpital's rule, one gets:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1 + e^{x}}{2}\right)^{1/x} & = \lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1 + e^{x}}{2}\right)\right) = \exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}}{1 + e^{x}}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{e}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

The logarithm gives us
$$
L := \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {1+e^{x}}{2}\right) ^{1/x} = \sqrt{e}
\implies
\ln(L) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\ln \left( \frac{1+e^x}{2} \right)} x 
$$
As $x \to 0$, this is a $0/0$-type form. Differentiate $x$ and the logarithm to apply L'Hopital's:
$$
\ln(L) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\left( \frac{1+e^x}{2} \right)} \cdot \frac 1 2 e^x
= \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} = \frac 1 2
$$
So $L = e^{1/2} = \sqrt e$.

Don't you need more details though to take the composition of functions? $ln$ needs to be continuous at x=0 for $((1 + e^x)/2)^{1/x}$, doesn't it?

No, the limit need only exist there.

That's what continuity means, but isn't that assuming the thing you're trying to show?

Continuity does not mean that the limit exists. A function $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)
$$
The fact that limit not only exists, but equals $f(x_0)$, is what defines continuity. The limit existing is what we need, not continuity.
